# Upload video from iPad - PHP

Tags: php, ipad

Stuck on some weird errors. Created an ipad web app to upload video from ipad gallery to my web server. Showing invalid file format, same video directly from desktop browser, working fine. Is there any issue with iPad or any mime type issue. See my code.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2400);
$path = "uploads/";

$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];


$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
$valid_formats = array("mp4", "MP4","jpg","avi","AVI");
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);

$errors = array(); 
$form_data = array();

if(!empty($name))
{
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
    {
        if ($size<(1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024))
        {
            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];

        } else {
            $errors['imgsize'] = 'Image file size max issue.<br/>';
        }

    } else{
        $errors['imgformat'] = 'Invalid file format..<br/>';
    }
}


if (!empty($errors)) {
    $form_data['success'] = false;
    $form_data['errors']  = $errors;
} else { 
    $form_data['success'] = true;
    $form_data['posted'] = '1';

    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name);
}

//Return the data back to form.php

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($form_data);   
?>
```

Comment: Change your error message to include the `$ext` and or the full `$_FILES['photoimg']['name'];`

Comment: What is that `if ($size < …)` line supposed to do? The number you're comparing to is about 2^50 times larger than the capacity of the observable universe. If you don't want to have a maximum, just remove the conditional altogether, or change it to `if(true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the similar issue, what ipad/iphone does it compresses & change the format to MOV whatever the format is. If you are uploading mp4, it will convert to MOV. Since your code does not check MOV format so its throwing an error. Add mov format and it will work. You are welcome :)

Comment: Thanks @roger, its fixed now.